# OnCalculate field in a table produces too long number

Tags: delphi

I have such a table in SQLite :

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE1] (
  [T_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT IGNORE AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [DATE] DATE UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [FIELD1] INTEGER, 
  [FIELD2] INTEGER, 
  [FIELD3] INTEGER, 
  [FIELD4] REAL);
```

I added a 2 new calculated fields to the TABLE1
called SUM1 (integer) and SUM2 (float).

```
procedure TForm3.UniTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM1').asInteger := (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD1').AsInteger) + (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD2').AsInteger) + (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD3').AsInteger);
UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM2').asFloat := (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM1').AsInteger) / (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD4').AsInteger) ;
end;
```

This kind of works but I am having trouble vwith SUM2 displaying a 15 digit number.

[image]

I would like to display a number with only two decimals like 5,81.
I could do it in the cxGrid by setting the properties of the field to CalcEdit and set Precision to 3.
But I am wondering can this be done in code.

Is there a way I can accomplish this ?

Comment: Well 314 / 54 is 5.8148148148148148148148148148148.  If you are using persistent fields you can set the DisplayFormat to ',0.00;; '

Comment: Nice answer David A ...forgot about the formats ...Post as answer if you will ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well 314 / 54 is 5.814814814814... . If you are using persistent fields you can set the DisplayFormat to ',0.00;; '

or in code:

```
TNumericField(UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM2')).DisplayFormat := ',0.00;; ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `FormatFloat('0.00',myvariable)` function.

'0.00' defines the format (2 decimal places), and myvariable is an aptly named variable.

The only drawbacks are that it requires an extra few lines of code to declare and assign a value to the variable, and if you wish to use this value for further calculations, the accuracy will be lower than the original floating point number you had.

```
    procedure TForm3.UniTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    var
      var1: real;
    begin
      //Assign the floating point value to the variable
      var1 := (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM1').AsInteger) / (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD4').AsInteger);
      UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM1').asInteger := UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD1').AsInteger) + (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD2').AsInteger) + (UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD3').AsInteger);          
      UNITable1.Fields.FieldByName('SUM2').AsFloat := FormatFloat('0.00',var1);
    end;
```

i haven't had a chance to test this, but the basic idea would be something along these lines.

Comment: This alternative would involve changing the field SUM2 to a TStringField type (in your code, for instance, this would reflect in correcting `'SUM2').AsFloat` to `'SUM2').AsString`). I believe the best way is to keep the TField numeric and just change the presentation of that value (`DisplayFormat`), just as suggested in the answer above.

Comment: It never hurts to learn more than one way, it may become useful in another situation :-). However, in this case I agree completely with you @GabrielF.